# Is it possible to code the "ticker symbol" using pine script on tradingview.com to display P&L values?

Tags: pine-script

I want the symbol chart on tradingview.com to display the P&L values when I hover on a particular candle using the mouse.

In the below image:

[image]

the symbol chart for "apple" displays the open, high, close, low values. These values change when I hover my mouse over any particular candle.

So what I would like is the symbol chart to also display values that calculate the P&L based on the close price. So for example, if the close price is 281.11 it should also display 2 additional columns that give me the values of 283.92 and 278.29 for a profit/loss of 1% respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Version 1

Can't be done. You can easily write a script that will show those values besides that script's name, but Pine scripts can't position values there.

#### Version 2

If you have multiple indies on your chart and want to bring this one under the symbol like this, select *Visual order/Bring to Front" in the indie's popup menu. You can change the % in the indie's *Inputs*:

```
//@version=4
study("P/L", "", true, scale = scale.none)
pct = input(1., "Percent Profit/Loss", step = 0.25, minval = 0.) / 100
plot(close * (1 + pct), "Profit", na)
plot(close * (1 - pct), "Loss", na)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Well it's not a necessity that the values should be displayed in the symbol chart. They can be displayed on another area in the chart but they should change on hover.

Comment: See v2 in answer.

Comment: thanks that's exactly what I wanted. Can you please explain this: pct = input(1., "Percent Profit/Loss", step = 0.25, minval = 0.) / 100
And how do I adjust the P/L values. For example if I wanted to calculate 2% profit and loss?

Comment: You access the script's *Inputs* through the cogwheel besides its name (see last screenshot in the answer). The line you referred to controls what you see in that db. It says: "Propose a 1% default value, which can't be lower than 0 and let the user change it in 0.25 increments with the arrows in the value's widget." You can also just enter any value you want instead of using the arrows to change it. The "/ 100" at the end of the line divides the user-friendly % value from the db into an internal representation better suited to the indie's calcs later on in the code.